# Python Selenium time.sleep() works implicitly_wait() and WebDriverWait fail

Tags: python, selenium

I am having an issue locating a web element by id using selenium and python.

This is just for one element on the page, I can find all others fine.

If I try to use

`driver.find_element_by_id("btUpdate").click()`

find_element_by_id it generates a

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:`

I get the same result if I add a

```
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
```

I get the same results if I use:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, id)))
```

However, if I put a simple time.sleep(2) before my find_element_by_id it then works.

Why does the sleep work, when the others fail? It will sit there waiting for 20 seconds with either wait command and still be unable to locate the element. Throw in a 2-second sleep and it finds it just fine.

Any ideas?

edit for additional info

Using Chrome with ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.70

Yes JeffC you are correct it does fail with a different error when I use WebDriverWait I get.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I also tried visibility_of_element_located but get the same TimeoutException.

Comment: Which web driver are you using, including version? Which browser version are you using?

Comment: If you are waiting for clickable using WebDriverWait, you aren't going to get a NoSuchElementException, you will get a timeout exception instead. Please post each code attempt, run it, and then post the full error message for each attempt. My guess is that you saw it fail but didn't realize it was failing with different messages. Those different messages may point you/us in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `element_to_be_clickable`, you could try waiting on a different condition -- `visibility_of_element_located` might help here.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "btUpdate")))

element.click()
```

Interesting problem, it's strange that `implicitly_wait` is not working for you here.

Comment: An element that is clickable according to Selenium is visible and not disabled so waiting for visible won't be any different (and may take slightly less time).

Comment: I think it really depends on the element. With newer Javascript frameworks that generate 'hacky' HTML, I've seen cases where `element_to_be_clickable` has timed out, because based on the DOM context, the element does not appear to be interactable, even if it is truly meant to be clicked.